# What is the abbreviation of A/D office in sec sic info?

Tags: abbreviations

What is the abbreviation of A/D office in sec cid ifo?

[image]

There are so many A/Ds in **http://www.abbreviations.com/AD**.

[so many A/Ds here](http://www.abbreviations.com/AD)

Maybe it is assistant director office?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your guess was right, it's Assistant Director. I found it by googling "A/D office" which turned up this  https://www.sec.gov/corpfin/Article/contact-us.html